# Set default sound card in Pulse Audio

Tags: linux, audio, pulseaudio

I have two soundcards on my systems and pulseaudio always picks the wrong one. How do I set up the default soundcard in the pulse audio preferences?

Answer (score 4):

Install *pavucontrol* and on the **Output devices** tab, toggle the "Check" button next to the little lock, on the device you want to mark as the default. Same for Input devices.

[image]

Comment: You must also go to the **Configuration tab** and set the other cards to **off**.  Specifically, HDMI often includes a video card (as audio) and a main CODEC as well.  They are both ALSA cards and most advice (like referenced AskUbuntu in another answer) do not tell you how to change the card.

Answer (score 1):

[I'd have a look at this question on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14077/how-can-i-change-the-default-audio-device-from-command-line). Also try out `pavucontrol`.