# Set default audio output device in Mate

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, bluetooth, mate-desktop

I have a laptop with Mint/Mate and bluetooth speakers. I can connect to the speakers using the bluetooth GUI. Then I click on the shortcut to the sound preferences GUI (`mate-volume-control` inside) and in the "output" tab, I pick the bluetooth speakers as output. Alright, this works fine.

However, each time the speakers are disconnected / reconnected, I need to go through that sound setting again.

Is there a GUI way to specify that the bluetooth speakers are the default output so that once they're connected, they take priority?

I also tried with `pavucontrol`, clicking "set as fallback" as described in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/63295/116842) but it does just the same: it outputs through the bluetooth speakers when I click, but I need to do it again every time. Is this expected behaviour?